# Improving large array manipulation

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, sparse-arrays

I am doing an iterative program, which uses large arrays/vectors and where the output of one round is used as an input for the next steps but works slowly when dimensions are bigger.
In brief, we create firstly the complex matrix s (dimension dos x dos) using SparseArray

```
    dos=101;
    s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1. + I, Band[{2, 1}] -> 2., 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> 2., Band[{dos + 1, 1}] -> 2.0, 
    Band[{1, dos + 1}] -> 2.0}, {dos*dos, dos*dos}, 0.];
```

And initial condition

```
    input=ConstantArray[1,{dos,dos}];
    input=Flatten[input];
    u1=input;
```

And finally, we do the iterative steps following some conditions/rules related to which position in the array is used

```
    lr = Table[i, {i, 1 + dos, dos*dos - dos, dos}];
    ll = Table[i, {i, dos + dos, dos*dos - dos, dos}];
    lt = Table[i, {i, 1, dos, 1}];
    lb = Table[i, {i, dos*dos - dos + 1, dos*dos, 1}];
    lll = Sort[Join[lr, ll, lt, lb]]; (*rules*)
    
    steps=50;
    Do[f = SparseArray[{{i_} :> 
       If[MemberQ[lll, i], 
        0, -2.0*u1[[i - 1]] - 2.0*u1[[i + 1]] - 2.0*u1[[i + dos]] - 
         2.0*u1[[i - dos]] + (1.+I)*u1[[i]]]}, {dos*dos}];
    u1 = LinearSolve[s, f];, {j, 1, steps, 1}]
```

This takes around 15 sec on my computer but with increasing dimensions, the time needed grows quickly. I noticed that applying LinearSolve is not slow, but creating the array f is where almost all the time is consumed. Is there a way to create f more efficiently? I tried to use Compile but not good results. Thanks in advance

Comment: That code throws errors on my machine; an extra bracket at the end plus some lists of unequal length in the `SparseArray`.  Have you enabled Evaluation>Debugger to see the timings of each call?

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I realized I did some mistakes when I wrote this question. I am editing it now with no errors

Comment: Why are you `Do`ing the `LinearSolve` 50 times?  Presumably `j` should be referenced somewhere in the loop.  I think your construction of `f` can be simplified by looking at small cases, and I think `SparseArray` isn't helping at all since you're manually specifying even 0 elements.  The speedup of `SparseArray` comes from specifying only a few nonzero ones.

Comment: @Adam  I tried to minimize the question. In every step j of my original code, I am saving each u1 on a table in order to plot it lately. Here I put 50 steps, but it could be 5000 or higher. About `SparseArray` not helping at all since I am manually specifying elements, I didn't know that, but for the moment is my fastest way to create `f`.

Comment: I also suggest to call `sinv = LinearSolve[s];` once. This will compute and store an LU-factorization of `s`. In the loop, you can simply use `u1 = sinv[f];` unstead of `u1 = LinearSolve[s, f];`. On my machine, this gets down the solve time from 3 seconds to only `0.06` seconds for the factorization and `0.08` seconds all the solves in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First OP's implementation with timing on my machine:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
 u1 = input;
 Do[f = SparseArray[{{i_} :> 
      If[MemberQ[lll, i], 
       0, -2.0*u1[[i - 1]] - 2.0*u1[[i + 1]] - 2.0*u1[[i + dos]] - 
        2.0*u1[[i - dos]] + (1. + I)*u1[[i]]]}, {dos*dos}];
  u1 = LinearSolve[s, f];, {j, 1, steps, 1}];
 result0 = u1;
 ]
```

> 17.1247

The computation of `f` from `u1` is linear and as such can be represented by the following sparse matrix:

```
A = Times[
    SparseArray[Partition[Complement[Range[dos dos], lll], 1] -> 1. + 0. I, {dos dos}, 0. I],
    SparseArray[{
      Band[{1, 1}] -> (1. + 1. I)
      , Band[{1, 1 + 1}] -> -2.0 + 0. I
      , Band[{1, 1 + dos}] -> -2.0 + 0. I
      , Band[{1 + 1, 1}] -> -2.0 + 0. I
      , Band[{1 + dos, 1}] -> -2.0 + 0. I
      },
     {dos dos, dos dos}, 0. I
     ]
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.053559

So, using also one-time factorization of `s`, OP's implementation can be rewritten into

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
 sinv = LinearSolve[s];
 u1 = input;
 Do[u1 = sinv[A.u1];, {j, 1, steps, 1}];
 result1 = u1;
 ]
```

> 0.141947

That is almost a 100-fold speedup.

This can also be formulated a bit shorter with `Nest` (which is not faster than `Do`):

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  sinv = LinearSolve[s];
  result2 = Nest[sinv[A.#] &, input, steps];
  ]
```

> 0.143743

Both lead to exactly the same result:

```
Max[Abs[result1 - result2]]
```

Comparison with OP's result:

```
Max[Abs[result1 - result0]]
```

> 541.03

Looks huge, but the relative error is much smaller:

```
Max[Abs[result1 - result0]]/Max[Abs[result0]]
```

> 1.64591*10^-14

What to learn from this: Pattern matching is all nice, but i maximizes rather programming speed, not execution speed.

Comment: thanks @Henrik Schumacher for your answer. I have several questions, but maybe they can be answered knowing the following, what is `idx`? (it is inside Partition when you define `A`)

Comment: Uh, sorry. I had forgotton to copy its definition from my notebook. I edited my answer; maybe it is clearer now. (The sparse vector in which `idx` is used is supposed to nullify a couple of rows of the banded matrix to which it is multiplied.)

Answer (score 1):

The following (and my comment) overlooks the fact that `u1` and `f` are dependent.  Copy code, don't rewrite it -- also don't over edit once copied!

---

When I look at `Normal@f` for various values of `dos`, I find the "edge" elements of `f` (considered as a `dos` by `dos` 2d grid) are 0 and the "inner" elements of `f` are `1.0I-7.0`.  Here, then, is a quicker way to construct such arrays

```
f=Join[
  0&/@Range@dos,
  Join@@(Append[Prepend[1.0I-7.0&/@Range[dos-2],0],0]&/@Range[dos-2]),
  0&/@Range@dos]
]
```

There are definitely faster/more efficient ways to construct `f`, but I think this may be a case of over-early-optimization.  If you're interested in situations for arbitrary rules `lll`, it may simply not be possible to speed things up.

<s>A good rule of thumb is to present the computationally hardest example you can think of in the question (i.e. a randomized set of rules, although this is probably not what you're interested in).  Of course, simple cases are useful for understanding the problem at hand.  And then there's the necessity of splitting up your problem into small, single-question-size parts.</s>

I think there's more that can be elucidated with further code exchange. The crossed out text detracts from this post.

Comment: thanks @Adam for your answer. It is true that inner elements are `1.0I-7.0` but only in the first step. In the following steps, those values are changing because `f` is not fixed, it is changing in every step

Comment: @DGtrauko my bad.  Copied code wrong, but my responses are a bit disrespectful.  Unfortunately I don't think I can improve on Henrik's answer!